# How to use enum in switch case

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I am trying to check what values are set in my VO.

Below are my clasess. I am getting
"**The qualified case label MyEnum.UserType.DOCTORS must be replaced with the unqualified enum constant DOCTORS**"

Please help me to identify what I am doing wrong here.

MyEnum.java

```
public MyEnum{
    private UserType userType;

    public UserType getUserType(){
        return userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(UserType userType){
        this.userType = userType;
    }

    public static enum UserType{
        DOCTORS("D"),
        PATIENT("P"),
        STAFF("S");
    }

}
```

EnumTest.java

```
public EnumTest {

    .....
    public void onGoBack(MyEnum myEnum) {

        switch(myEnum.getUserType())
        {
            case UserType.DOCTORS: // this shows "The qualified case label MyEnum.UserType.DOCTORS must be replaced with the unqualified enum constant DOCTORS"
                break;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: try using `case DOCTORS:` instead as suggested by the compiler.

Comment: Why don't you just try and do what the error message says you should do?

Comment: I find it useful to have this question at least once in SO, and number of upvotes mean ppl agree with me. This syntax is pretty unusual where u can use an unqualified constant name when being out of the class where the constant is defined.

Comment: The error also sports some very technical language which many won't get right off the bat.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Since the compiler knows what type of enum you're evaluating in the switch statement, you should drop the "qualified" portion as the error suggests (in your case: `MyEnum.UserType.`) and simply use the "unqualified" enum `DOCTORS`. See below:

```
switch(myEnum.getUserType())
{
    case DOCTORS: 
        break;
}
```

Comment: Was it really harder to read the error message than to post a question on SO and wait for an answer? `:/`

Comment: What about if you have another constant called the same thing in another class? Wouldn't `DOCTORS` be ambiguous in that case?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye no, it would not be ambiguous, because the compiler knows exactly which enum type the `switch` expression evaluates to.

Comment: Matt Ball, we're all at different levels of experience.  No need to berate/belittle someone who thanked you for your help.  Let's keep it professional. This user took the time to ask the question and probably just needed a little guidance about how to interpret the error message.  I personally am just learning Java, and I came here because I didn't know the answer merely by the exception either.

Comment: Matt Ball, this Question seems legitimate and sensible to me. Given that we can use `MyEnum.ABC` &  `MyEnum.XYZ` everywhere else in Java, I was surprised and confused to find this same syntax to be illegal in a `switch - case`.